# Не получается в одном выражении совершить несколько операций с экземплярами класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В общем, реализую класс матрица, перегружаю операторы сложения и присваивания, чтобы две матрицы сложить и присвоить третей в результате следующего действия:   С=А+В, но оператор присваивания не срабатывает. Только в отдельном выражении. Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
public:
    const static size_t n = 4;
    double arr[n][n];
    Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
    }
    Matrix(int k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = rand()%101 ;
            }
    }
    void showArr(char);
    Matrix operator + (Matrix &a);
    Matrix operator = (Matrix &a);
    float operator[] (size_t i)
    {
        return arr[i][i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(0, "");
    char A[2] = { "A" };
    char B[2] = { "B" };
    char C[2] = { "C" };
    Matrix a(1);
    Matrix b(2);
    Matrix c;
    a.showArr(A[0]);
    b.showArr(B[0]);
    c=a+b;
    c.showArr(C[0]);
    system("pause");
}

Matrix Matrix::operator+ (Matrix& a)
{
    double c[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            a.arr[i][j]+= arr[i][j];
    }
    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix :: operator = (Matrix &a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            arr[i][j] = a.arr[i][j];
    }
    return *this;
}

void Matrix::showArr(char A)
{
    cout << "Матрица " << A << ":" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (arr[i][j] >= 10)
                {
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
                else
                    cout <<" "<<  arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        else {
            cout << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (arr[i][j] >= 10)
                {
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }
                else
                    cout << " " << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl<< endl;
}
```

Comment: `Matrix(int k)` - прям как создатели перегрузки инкремента - а давайте мы какую-нибудь фигню аргументом передадим, просто чтобы различить, а использовать всё равно не будем.

Comment: `char A[2] = { "A" };` - тут что-то не то с типами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` работакет как `+=`. Ты там вообще `c` не используешь.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator + (Matrix& a)
{
    Matrix c;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            с.arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] + a.arr[i][j];

    return с;
}
```

Comment: Да, пытался там что-то менять, в коде, потом забыл обратно изменить. Если не сложно, подскажите, как `с` вернуть, чтобы не менять поля исходных матриц.

Comment: @АлександрЕфремов

Answer (score 0):

Оператор сложения логически неверный.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+ (Matrix& a)
{
    double c[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            a.arr[i][j]+= arr[i][j];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Он не складывает две матрицы, a присваивает значения одной матрицы другой. Более того он присваивает значения правому операнду от знака сложения, что лишь запутывает пользователей вашей программы.

```
a.arr[i][j]+= arr[i][j];
```

И к тому же возвращает временный объект который соответствует оставшемуся без изменений левому операнду.

То есть если есть запись

```
c = a + b;
```

то в ней матрица `b` не прибавляется к матрице `a` и более того матрица `c` не содержит результата сложения.

То есть код совершенно неверный.

Что касается ошибки, то проблема в том, что данный оператор возвращает временный объект, а оператор присваивания у вас определен таким образом, что он имеет в качестве параметра неконстантную ссылку.

```
Matrix Matrix :: operator = (Matrix &a)
                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

А неконстантная ссылка не может быть связана с временным объектом. Поэтому если даже не принимать во внимание те недочеты оператора сложения, на которые я указал, данное предложение

```
c = a + b;
```

не должен компилироваться.

Так как в вашем классе все члены класса имеют класс доступа `public` , то оператор сложения можно объявить в виде отдельной функции не члена класса.

Он может выглядеть следующим образом

```
const Matrix Matrix::operator +( const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b )
{
    Matrix result;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            result.arr[i][j] = a.arr[i][j] + b.arr[i][j];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Оператор присваивания, который естественно является методом класса в отличии от оператора сложения, должен иметь константную ссылку в качестве параметра

```
Matrix Matrix::operator =( сщтые Matrix &a )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            arr[i][j] = a.arr[i][j];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Также непонятно ваше определение оператора индексирования. Помимо того, что он должен по крайней мере иметь тип возвращаемого значения `double`, а не `float`

```
float operator[] (size_t i)
^^^^^
{
    return arr[i][i];
}
```

он, вообще-то, не имеет смысла.

Есть у вас и другие недочеты в программе.

Например, неясно, какое значение имеет параметр `k` в этом конструкторе

```
Matrix(int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand()%101 ;
        }
}
```

Так как он нигде не используется.

Более того в обоих конструкторах вы должны использовать статическую константу `n` , а не магическое число `4`.

Если вам надо иметь два конструктора, один из которых инициализирует массив нулями, а другой случайными значениями, то вы просто могли бы bvtnm jlby rjycnhernjh b объявить tuj параметр, как имеющий тип `bool`, и указать аргумент по умолчанию.

Например

```
Matrix( bool random = false );
```

Метод `showArr` правильно было бы объявить с параметром типа `const char *` и передавать в качестве аргумента не один символ, а строку.

Кроме того следует сделать метод константным:

```
void showArr( const char * ) const;
```

И с реализацией данного метода у вас что-то странное и непонятное.:) Уверен, что он тоже некорректный.

Comment: Эм.. А с каких пор `*this` - это временный объект? И аргумент оператора в виде переменной при объявлении передачи по ссылке - это же тоже не временный объект. По поводу `showArr` - да, там жесть, но вроде работать может.

Comment: @Qwertiy Возвращаемое значение функции - это временный объект, который создается копированием объекта *this.

Comment: А, точно. Я что-то слишком привык, что когда делают `return *this;`, то возвращают ссылку, и просмотрел, что оператор объявлен не как `Matrix & operator + (Matrix &a);`, а просто `Matrix operator + (Matrix &a);`.

Comment: метод `showArr` реализован таким образом, чтобы в матрица выглядела ровной по разряду единиц. Зачем делать метод константным?

Comment: @АлександрЕфремов Этот метод не изменяет сам объект, а потому, чтобы его можно было вызывать для константных объектов, например, когда матрица передается по константной ссылке в какую-нибудь функцию, или когда возвращается константная матрица из функции, то этот метод можно было бы применить.